# Can't call overloaded operator C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I can't call overloaded + operator that sums my two wrapper objects.

Code from Vector.cpp:

```
//Overload operators
Vector operator + (const Vector & lhc, const Vector& rhc)
{

    long shorterLength;
    if(lhc.numberOfElements > rhc.numberOfElements)
    {
        shorterLength = rhc.numberOfElements;
    }
    else
    {
        shorterLength = lhc.numberOfElements;
    }

    //Vector *vector = new Vector(shorterLength, true);

    Vector vector;
    for(int i = 0; i<shorterLength; i++)
    {
        vector.container.push_back(lhc.container[i]+ rhc.container[i]);
    }

    return vector;
}
```

And in Vector.h

```
Vector(long numerOfElements, bool isEmpty);
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    Vector operator + (const Vector& rhc);
```

In main.cpp. I can't call + operator on my Vector instances getting "Invalid operator to binary expression Vector * Vector *" error.

```
  Vector *a = new Vector(10, false);
    a->displayElements();

    Vector *b = new Vector(5, false);
    b->displayElements();
    Vector c;


    //c = a + b
    //If I comment this out I get c = a + b;
  //  Invalid operator to binary expression Vector * Vector *
```

Comment: You have both member and non-member versions of the operator. On top of that, you are trying to add a pointer to a Vector.

Comment: Any particular reason for `new`:ing the `vector`s?

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to add two pointers. If you really want to muck around with `new` for some reason, then you'll need to dereference the pointers

```
c = *a + *b;
```

but you'd almost certainly be better off with objects

```
Vector a(10, false);
Vector b(5, false);
Vector c = a + b;
```

Then decide whether the overloaded operator should be a member (as you declare it) or a non-member (as you define it), and make both the declaration and the definition match.

Answer (score 1):

First you have two overloads of `operator+`.

Second you are using `operator+` on pointers and pointers cannot be added.

```
c = a + b;   <<<< Adding pointers doesn't make sense.
```

You can do something like:-

```
Vector a(10, false);
Vector b((5, false);
Vector c = a + b;
```